# How does java know when in a PriorityQueue , an items key is changed in order to re-heapify the changed node

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

```
    class PQItem implements Comparable<PQItem>{
public int key;

public PQItem(int key) {
    this.key = key;

}

@Override
public int compareTo(PQItem o) {
    return this.key - o.key;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.key+"";
}
```

}

```
    PriorityQueue<PQItem> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
    PQItem pq1 = new PQItem(45);
    PQItem pq2 = new PQItem(1);
    PQItem pq3 = new PQItem(4);
    PQItem pq4 = new PQItem(3);

    pq.offer(pq1);
    pq.offer(pq2);
    pq.offer(pq3);
    pq.offer(pq4);

    pq1.key = 40;
    pq2.key = -4;

    System.out.println(pq.poll());
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
    System.out.println(pq.poll());
```

Above prints as expected in sorted order
-4
3
4
40

The question is I want to know if the operation of changing the key was done in O(lg n) with a Heapify on the changed node.If it was done, how does java detect me setting a property on one of the objects in order to trigger the heapify procedure on that node.

Comment: It does not (cannot) detect any of that.

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, and it specifically says so in the Javadoc.

The key changes you performed happened to be benign, as they didn't affect the ordering. You got lucky. Don't rely on it.

Comment: makes sense. thanks!